# CSS Relative children take height of parent

Tags: html, css, responsive

I have a parent div with padding, inside there are 2 children. I want for second child b to take the rest of the height of parent (minus div a). And if div a is not present, than take all height. (with same css!)

```css
#parent {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  max-width: 500px;
  max-height: 200px;
  background: #333;
  top: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#parent:after {
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  display: block;
  content: '';
}

.a {
   position: relative;
  height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}

.b {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: blue;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="a">1 </div>
  <div class="b">2 </div>
</div>
```

---

edit:

why was the question downvoted? What is wrong with the question? how do I ask it without being downvoted?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `view-height` css unit for div `b`. Example with your code. If you remove div `a` you will notice that div `b` will take all the `height`.

```css
#parent {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  max-width: 500px;
  max-height: 200px;
  background: #333;
  top: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#parent:after {
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  display: block;
  content: '';
}

.a {
   position: relative;
  height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
}

.b {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: blue;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="a">1 </div>
  <div class="b">2 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Lucky for you he is using `overflow: hidden;` on the `#parent` element.

Comment: @caramba Well I think he wanted for us to adjust his code, I can write from scratch with different code, but that's not the point.

Comment: This is not correct, if I use console, I can see blue div is higher than 180px (as it should be).

Comment: @Toniq I don't quite understand what's the issue.

Comment: if the parent is 200px high, a 20px high, then b must be 180px high, but its much higher and only parent overflow hides the rest, which is not good. b must be 500x180 in this example.

Answer (score 0):

The intended behaviour can be achieved with `flex-box` layouts, as demonstrated in the Code Snippet embedded below.

**Solution Breakdown:**

1. `#parent` - declare `flex` on containing parent element, as well as
   `flex-wrap` so that nested elements can occupy the full-width of the
   container, we want to maintain the *row direction* here.
2. `.a` - declare `flex-basis` on this nested element; which is
   tantamount to declaring `width: 100%` - we want it to remain
   full-width so that the following sibling element (`.b`) wraps to a
   new row.
3. `.b` - declare the shorthand property `flex: 1 1` to specify that
   this element should occupy the full width and height of its
   containing element but not exceed it. The `flex`<sup>[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex)</sup> property is a
   shorthand for `flex-shrink`<sup>[2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink)</sup>,
   `flex-grow`<sup>[3](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow)</sup>, and `flex-basis`<sup>[4](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis)</sup>

```css
#parent {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  max-width: 500px;
  max-height: 200px;
  background: #333;
  top: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* additional */
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#parent:after {
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  display: block;
  content: '';
}

.a {
  position: relative;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
  /* additional */
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

.b {
  position: relative;
  background: blue;
  /* additional */
  flex: 1 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="a">1</div>
  <div class="b">2</div>
</div>
<br>
<div id="parent">
  <div class="b">2</div>
</div>
```

*A note on `flex-box`:*
Since `flex-box` has limited to no support for legacy browsers (like I.E) for full browser support and compatibility refer to either one of the aforementioned alternatives.

**See browser compatibility:**

1. [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#search=flex)
2. [flex - CSS | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex#Browser_compatibility)

*Edit*

**Updated**

```css
#parent {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  max-width: 500px;
  max-height: 200px;
  background: #333;
  top: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* additional */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 200px; /* an absolute height value is required for relative flex-box heights */
}

/*#parent:after { kill the interloper
  padding-top: 56.25%;
  display: block;
  content: '';
}*/

.a {
  position: relative;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
}

.b {
  position: relative;
  background: blue;
  /* additional */
  flex: 1 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="a">1</div>
  <div class="b">2</div>
</div>
<br>
<div id="parent">
  <div class="b">2</div>
</div>
```

The updated snippet demonstrates an alternative solution with a *column direction*. The *pseudo-element* `#parent:after` has been removed as it negates any attempt to achieve the behaviour specified in your question (if this *pseudo-element* is required in any shape or form, consider updating your question to point this out with clear explanations as to its function and or role).

Comment: This is not correct, if I use console, I can see blue div is higher than 180px (as it should be).

Comment: @Toniq Tell me, will the height of the containing parent element be *dynamic* or is it *fixed* a `200px`?

Comment: @Toniq Also is there any particular reason why you have a *pseudo-element* with a `padding-top` property value of `56.25%`? This seems like a very arbitrary number and its role/function is not clear. What is apparent though is that this is the source of the issue you've pointed out in your comment. Negating this *pseudo-element* allows the `flex-box` module to behave as intended.

Comment: Parent height should be dynamic with 16/9 ratio, thats why there is a padding.